# How can I make the Microsoft C++ compiler treat unknown flags as errors rather than warnings?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, build, build-process

For various reasons, I would like to be able to script the detection of whether the MS C++ compiler honors a particular flag. I'm using the compiler from the Windows 7.1 SDK:

```
C:\> cl /version
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

So lets say I want to know if the flag `/GLEFGB` is supported by this compiler (which it is not, because it doesn't exist):

```
C:\>cl /c ./foo.cc /GLEFBG
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/GEFBG'
foo.cc
```

OK, good start, but it is a warning, and it doesn't set the exit status to invalid:

```
C:\>echo %errorLevel%
0
```

So we should be done if we turn on warnings as errors with `/WX`, right?

```
C:\>cl /c ./foo.cc /WX /GLEFBG

Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/GEFBG'
foo.cc
```

Wrong. This is getting disappointing. Maybe D9002 isn't captured by `/WX` for some reason? Maybe we can explicitly make it an error by using `/we` with that code? Care to guess whether this will work?

```
C:\>cl /c ./foo.cc /WX /weD9002 /GLEFBG
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/weD9002'
```

Nope, now we error out because apparently the tag for this compiler warning is not a legal argument to `/we`. I also tried `/we9002`, which doesn't work either.

So, now I am out of ideas. Any thoughts on how to convince `cl` to error out with a non-zero exit status if passed an invalid flag? It is really hard to interrogate the compiler for flag support without this sort of behavior.

Comment: Warning options apply only to the code that compiler parses, not to the command line arguments.  There is no option to make it fail this way.

Comment: OK, so how can you determine if the compiler supports a given flag?

Comment: Type `cl /?` to see supported options.

Comment: How can I *programmatically* determine if the compiler supports a given flag?

Comment: Redirect the output?  This is getting a bit silly, the options the compiler supports are well documented in the MSDN Library.

Comment: @HansPassant No, it isn't silly. It actually is very important: many build systems have a "configure" like stage at the beginning during which they detect whether the toolchain offers certain features. A common way to do this is to try to invoke the compiler with the flag, and examine the exit status, under the theory that the compiler will reject the invalid flag with an error. The fact that this compiler doesn't offer this behavior is problematic.

Comment: This is an XY question.  You'll never get anywhere with the way you are hoping to implement it.  Update your question to describe what you want to accomplish.  And be sure to include an example of such a build system, include the [tag] for it so that somebody that knows it can explain how they did it for the MSVC compiler.

Comment: @HansPassant, I dont think its too much to ask to be able to *programmatically* detect compiler errors (for both syntax and cmd line errors). The most standard way to do this is to check the compiler return value, as other common compilers such as gcc do. Having to parse the compiler output is definitely not a viable option. Apparently the Microsoft compiler always returns success, irregardless of what happens, which seems rather short-sighted.

Comment: @HansPassant I've written such a post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274521/using-scons-trycompile-to-examine-compiler-flag-support-on-windows, and also filed an enhancement request for MSVC with Microsoft connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/781052/cl-compiler-should-honor-wx-and-or-wecode-for-command-line-argument-warnings

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem. While `cl` doesn't report them you could perhaps check the output from `cl`.

I ended up writing a python script that executes another program and if that program returns error or the program writes anything to `stderr` the script reports failur (ie exit code 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess
import sys

proc = subprocess.Popen(sys.argv[1:], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

got_error = False

for l in proc.stderr:
    try:
        print(str(l, errors="replace"), end="")
    except TypeError:
        print(str(l), end="")
    got_error = True

proc.wait()

if got_error or proc.poll() != 0:
    sys.exit(1)
```

I've tried it under cygwin, but it should work under dos prompt too (perhaps you will have to specifically call it with python interpreter):

```
python3 chkerr cl /c ./foo.cc /GLEFBG
```

where `chkerr` is the name I gave to the script.