# Using SCons TryCompile to examine compiler flag support on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, warnings, configure, scons

With GCC and clang, I've been able to use SCons 'TryCompile' feature to build a simple configure check to determine if the currently configured compiler supports a given compile flag. Basically, clone the env, add the flag in question to CFLAGS, CCFLAGS, or CXXFLAGS, as appropriate, execute TryCompile, and if the TryCompile succeeds, then the flag is supported and we can add it to the real env.

- This works perfectly with gcc, because unknown flags are errors and the compiler exits with a non-zero status.
- With clang, it works reasonably well too: clang by default treats unknown errors as warnings, but if you pass it -Werror it will turn unknown flags into errors. So my wrapper around TryCompile just always passes -Werror along with the flag to be tested if it knows we are using clang.

However, this all falls over with the Microsoft toolchain because as far as I can discover, there is *no way* to convince the compiler to treat unknown flags as errors: they are always warnings, even if you pass the flag to make warnings errors. Since the compile exits cleanly wither or not the flag is accepted, TryCompile always succeeds. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259720/how-can-i-make-the-microsoft-c-compiler-treat-unknown-flags-as-errors-rather-t) for details on the various attempts I have made to get MSVC to exit with a non-zero status.

Any ideas on how I can make this work? Is there another SCons facility that I'm overlooking that can do this job for me? Should I interpose on TryCompile on MS platforms and parse the compiler output rather than examining the exit status. I'm really happy with using TryCompile for configure time flag detection with clang and gcc, but if I can't get MSVC to cooperate I'm going to need to abandon this whole approach, and I'm pretty loathe to do that since it is working so well so far.

Answer (score 1):

Leave it to Windows to rain on the parade once again :) Obviously the Windows compiler always returns success, irregardless of what happens.

I can think of several options that you could try.

First of all, SCons provides a [Multi-Platform Configuration (Autoconf Functionality)](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.2.0/HTML/scons-user/c4241.html) which may help you achieve the same result. It doesnt include anything for compiler options, but does at least includes the following:

- Checking for the Existence of Header Files
- Checking for the Availability of a Function
- Checking for the Availability of a Library
- Checking for the Availability of a typedef
- Adding Your Own Custom Checks

Another option would be to build some sort of a dictionary with the Microsoft compilation options. You would probably need one dictionary per compiler version. This particular option would probably take a long time to prepare, and probably wouldnt be worth it.

Another option would be to use the Object() or Program() builder instead of the TryCompile() builder, and try to *catch* the failure and react accordingly. Im not sure if SCons allows you to catch compilation failures as an exception and carry on if it fails, but its worth checking into.

Comment: Yeah really. I am using the Multi-Platform Configuration stuff already though: that is where TryCompile comes from. I'm not sure Object or Program will help since I think the still rely on exit status.

Comment: @acm, I think the Object/Program would indeed be able to detect the error by checking if the resulting target is created.

Comment: Right, but it still will be created, because using the unsupported flag only causes a warning which doesn't prevent the compilation from producing output.

Comment: @acm, Ahh, I see. That just doesnt make sense... wait its Microsoft ;)

Comment: I've filed an enhancement request via microsoft connect. Please upvote there if you can: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/781052/cl-compiler-should-honor-wx-and-or-wecode-for-command-line-argument-warnings